# Array displays length of 0 sometimes

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am having an extremely bizarre problem. I have a Backbone collection, and I am using the where method to find models in the collection that match a certain attribute. My problem is the inconsistency of the results.

I have a joinedGoalList which keeps track of goals that a user has joined. Let's say that this collection contains two goals with IDs of 1 and 3. When a user accesses /goals/3, a message should display saying that the user has joined the goal

I am having a problem where I am accessing /goals/3, and half the time the message displays, and the other half of the time, the message does not display.

The odd thing is that this problem only happens on my remote server and not on my local host.

In my code, I query the joinedGoalList for an ID of 3, and if it matches, I know that the matches array has to be greater than 0, so I render the message showing that the user has joined the goal.

Here is the code (joinedGoalList is a Backbone collection:

```
  console.log(joinedGoalList);
  var matches = joinedGoalList.where({id: this.model.get("id")});
  console.log(matches);
  console.log(matches.length);
  if (matches.length > 0) {
    console.log("the matches length is > 0");
    this.renderLeaveGoal();
  } else {
    console.log("the matches length is 0");
    this.renderJoinGoal();
  }
```

Here are the results of `console.log(joinedGoalList)`, here are the results(they are consistent):

```
child
_byCid: Object
_byId: Object
_callbacks: Object
length: 2
models: Array[2]
__proto__: ctor
```

As you can see, the length is 2. One of the objects has an ID of 1 and the other object has an ID of 3. This is consistent throughout the page loads.

The inconsistency occurs when I do a match on the array for an object with an ID of 3. Some page loads find the match while other page loads do not find the match.

The results of `console.log(matches.length)` are either 0 or 1 on my remote server, yet on my localhost, the results are always 1.

Comment: "only happens on my remote server" smells like a race condition to me

Comment: Are you sure you're not checking the collection before it has been populated with data from the server? The underlying `fetch` will is asynchronous after all.

Comment: I'd suggest also logging the IDs of the models in the collection to the console so you can be sure what you have there. Is the model you're querying for definitely saved, or otherwise has `id` set, at that point? Side note, why use `where()` here -- why not `joinedGoalList.get( this.model.get( 'id' ) )`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that the sequence of events goes like this:

1. You call [`fetch`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-fetch) on the collection to load your data from the server.
2. You call `console.log(joinedGoalList)`, this is asynchronous in some browsers.
3. You call [`joinedGoalList.where`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-where) and find an empty collection.
4. The `fetch` call from **1** returns and populates the collection.
5. The `console.log` call from **2** executes and prints out the populated collection, this call will have a reference to `joinedGoalList` and that reference will now be pointing at a populated collection.

When you do this locally, the AJAX `fetch` in **4** returns quite quickly so step **4** occurs before **3** and everything behaves the way you'e expecting it to.

You have a couple options here:

1. `fetch` has a `success` callback:

   > The **options** hash takes `success` and `error` callbacks which will be passed `(collection, response)` as arguments.

   So you could use the `success` callback to delay whatever is calling `where` until the server has responded and the collection is populated.
2. `fetch` resets the collection:

   > When the model data returns from the server, the collection will reset.

   and [`reset`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-reset) will

   > replace a collection with a new list of models (or attribute hashes), triggering a single `"reset"` event at the end.

   So you could listen for the `"reset"` event and use that event to trigger whatever is calling `where`.